# Getting the edited python module

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

This file was saved as `task1.py` and saved in `C:\Python27\task1.py` so as it can be imported as module

```
def test():
    return "This is a test module"

print test()
```

This is `task2.py` used to test the created module

```
import task1

def testmod():
    return task1.test()

print testmod()
```

After running `task2.py` this is the result:

```
(1)task2.py ===========
This is a test module
This is a test module
```

This is my desired result

```
(2)task2.py ===========
This is a test module
```

So I go `task1.py` at `C:\Python27\task1.py` and edit it to

```
def test():
    return "This is a test module"
```

Deleting the `print test()`
Now from here if I run `task2.py` am still getting `(1)` instead of `(2)`
Tried to use `reload()` but I don't know where I go wrong, please assist

Comment: Have you removed any *.pyc files lying around in the directory?

Comment: `reload()` has no use if you just running things like `python task2.py`.

Comment: I am using the  `IDLE (Python GUI)` to run things

Comment: Have you reloaded both task1 and task2 (in that order)?

Comment: I think so, probably I am missing something; Can you try it in your machine and show it over here; in a kind of layman terms; using `IDLE (Python GUI)`

Comment: I just run scripts from the terminal. This is one of the reasons I don't run scripts from an IDE.